# Tablet-only app not visible in Google Play

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I have mentioned the following in the manifest ,

```
                  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="false"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
```

And uploaded in the google play store. On Goole play developer console 73 devices are shown as a supported device for my app eg: Nexus 7 supported. But when i search my app from Nexus 7 or any other tablet app is not displayed in the play store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I found your app in Google Play, and clicked on Permissions, it showed "Phone calls: directly call phone numbers". Does your manifest specify "requires phone"? Many tablets have no phone. You probably want your manifest to say

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```